# How to create objects of class using CUDA/C++?

Tags: c++, cuda

I want to create an array of class objects and this array has to be accessible by my GPU.

I have 3 files:

1. My class header file "Person.h"

```
    #pragma once
    
    #include <iostream>
    
  
    class Person
    {
    private:
        std::string name, surname;
        int age;
    
    public:
        Person();
        void print();
    
    };
```

2. "Person.cpp" file:

```
    #include "Person.h"
    
    
    Person::Person()
    {
        name = "John";
        surname = "Smith";
        age = 50;
    }
    
    void Person::print()
    {
        std::cout << "Name: " << name << ", Surname: " << surname << ", Age: " << age << std::endl;
    }
```

3. "main.cu" file:

```
    #include "cuda_runtime.h"
    #include "device_launch_parameters.h"
    
    #include "Person.h"
    
    int main()
    {
        int size = 3;
        Person* person_array;
        cudaMallocManaged(&person_array, size * sizeof(Person));
    
    
        std::cout << "Initialized array: " << std::endl;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            person_array[i].print();
        }
    
    
        cudaFree(person_array);
    }
```

Program compiles, however it shows wrong results. It prints:

> Initialized array:
> Name: , Surname: , Age: 0
> Name: , Surname: , Age: 0
> Name: , Surname: , Age: 0

It looks like the default constructor is not called.

What am I doing wrong?

## ========
EDIT:

Thanks for the answers.
It seems to be complicated.
I am new in CUDA and connection of object oriented programming with it is hard to understand. Moreover, there is not many information about it in the Internet.

I have a bigger project, which uses OOP and I need to implement CUDA into it. I try to do this first with simple examples.

Maybe you can help me with this?
So, lets say that I just want to make a method, which adds x to the age of an object. Thus, my "Person.h" file will be:

"Person.h":

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>


class Person
{
private:
    std::string name, surname;
    int age;

public:
    Person();
    void addXToAge(int x);

};
```

"Person.cpp":

```
#include "Person.h"


Person::Person()
{
    name = "John";
    surname = "Smith";
    age = 50;
}

void Person::addXToAge(int x)
{
    age += x;
}
```

"main.cu":

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include "Person.h"

int main()
{
    int size = 3;
    Person* person_array = new Person[size];
    

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        person_array[i].addXToAge(10);
    }


    delete[] person_array;
}
```

Now, I want to modify the program, so that the addXToAge(int x) function will be called by the kernel and 3 threads will be used to calculate the new age of the objects.

How to do that?

Comment: Note that the GPU is unlikely to understand `class Person`, even though it can access the memory of `person_array`.

Comment: You can't. There is no C++ standard library support on the device in CUDA. std::string can't be used.

Answer (score 2):

You print `"Initialized array: "`, but that is just wrong. It's not an array, and it's not initialized. `person_array` is just enough memory to hold the bytes of 3 `Person`s

You either need to deal with placement new yourself, of wrap `cudaMallocManaged` in an allocator interface so that `std::vector<ValueType, Allocator>` can use it. By default `std::vector<T>` uses `std::allocator` which calls regular `new`)

You can't call the constructor directly, and you are correct in observing that the constructor is not called. C++ calls the constructor for you, but `cudaMallocManaged` is a C function.